# Google Analytics _trackPageview AJAX requests 100% bounce rates

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a form (made up of a few stages) that is loaded via ajax, and as I move between stages I want to track it in Google Analytics as a PageView. I have this working ok, but I am getting an overall bounce rate below 100% (~30%), which is fine. But when I look at the individual pages, they all seem to have a bounce rate of 100%. I am not too sure if this is normal, or should I expect different bounce rates? I have included some snippets below.

Thanks

Andy

```
//Run at the start
_gat._createTracker('UA-xxxxxxxx-4', 'myTracker');
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['myTracker._setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-4']);
_gaq.push(['myTracker._setDomainName', 'www.testaccount.co.uk']);

//This is run when a stage loads up.
_gaq.push(['myTracker._trackPageview', '/form/stage[X]/']);

//This code is run within each stage to capture elements of the form being completed
_gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', 'Test', "value"]);
```

Comment: I am not sure if using _setReferrerOverride will help...

Comment: Can you add a link to the site you're trying to run this on?

Answer (score 1):

Bounce rate issues like the one you are seeing are typically the result of cookie-domain issues. If you're trying to isolate the top-level www domain, I would try passing 'none' as the argument for _setDomainName. '*trackPageview' both creates and reads cookies, so I'm guessing it's creating duplicate sets of '*_utm' cookies on your site.

Check out the documentation for '_setDomainName', specifically the section on isolating top-level domains, at: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setDomainName